# Creating a CSS class that changes a cards background color

Tags: oracle-apex

I currently am trying to change the background color of specific cards in Oracle APEX version 20.2.  I'm currently trying to pass a class through the #CARD_MODIFIERS# field that is available within the cards template option in the classic report region but I am having trouble defining a class that colors the entire background of the card as opposed to just the border.  I also explored the #CARD_COLOR# field but this only displays the color when you hover over a card.  If there was a way to make this color persist, that would be an acceptable solution.

My class currently looks like this

```css
.card {
  background-color: springgreen;
 }
```

This class gives a border around the card with the springgreen color but I want the color of the card itself to be given this value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 20.2 you can use Card region which I think will be much easier to customise. Take a look here - https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/a-simple-guide-to-the-new-cards-region-in-apex-202

For changing the background, with Card region you can use Universal Theme colors - https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/color-and-status-modifiers

Update:

In the property editor under attributes, add color class as on screenshot below.

[image]

Cards:

[image]

Comment: I have tried using the card region before and I am struggling to get the entire background of any of the cards to change to anything but white can you try to guide me on how to implement the universal theme colors?

Comment: Sure, take a look at my answer I edited it.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me after adding 'u-color-1' to that field my card backgrounds are still white

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of it? I think it should work

Comment: Did you add u-color-1 under Card > CSS Classes as on the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, in the attributes tab of the card region itself

Comment: What appearance settings are you using in your cards region? Could that change something (template, style option, etc.)

Comment: Template is Card Container

Comment: Mine is as well but my cards don't look like yours formatting wise, I also don't have any inline CSS on my page

Comment: I'll try to do that and let you know once I do